# Desktop Computer - Detecting type of internet connection

Tags: networking, connection

Is there any way to detect if my computer is connected via cable or mobile network to the internet?

I tried to analyze the trace-route output but realized that it would need a very large and up-to-date database to detect the type of network the data packages take.

Have this two different types of network maybe some different attributes that are easily to detect?

Comment: Are you trying to determine if you are wired (Ethernet) or connected via cellular? Is this Windows?

Comment: That's right. And I'm using Windows.

Comment: Another follow up question. Is your goal essentially trying to determine if you are using a costed (pay to use) network as apposed to a free on (Ethernet or wifi)?

Comment: No, my goal is to avoid sending two message over the same network (wired or cellular). I'd like to send one message over the Internet and the other over the mobile phone network. It's due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NetworkListManager APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965303(v=vs.85).aspx) to find if a network is connected to the internet. The example below does both that and checks to see if the network is free. You can just remove the Cost related code:

```
HRESULT GetFreeInternetInterface(_Out_ GUID* pInterfaceGuid)
{
    bool fCoInitialized = false;
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        fCoInitialized = true;
        CComPtr<INetworkListManager> pNetworkListManager; 
        hr = pNetworkListManager.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(NetworkListManager));
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            CComPtr<IEnumNetworkConnections> pNetworkConnections;
            hr = pNetworkListManager->GetNetworkConnections(&pNetworkConnections);

            bool fFound = false;
            while (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                CComPtr<INetworkConnection> pNetworkConnection;
                hr = pNetworkConnections->Next(1, &pNetworkConnection, nullptr);
                if (hr == S_OK)
                {
                    CComPtr<INetworkConnectionCost> pNetworkConnectionCost;
                    hr = pNetworkConnection.QueryInterface(&pNetworkConnectionCost);

                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        NLM_CONNECTIVITY nlmConnectivity = NLM_CONNECTIVITY_DISCONNECTED;
                        DWORD dwCost = NLM_CONNECTION_COST_UNKNOWN;
                        if (SUCCEEDED(pNetworkConnection->GetConnectivity(&nlmConnectivity)) &&
                            (nlmConnectivity & (NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV4_INTERNET | NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV6_INTERNET)) != 0 &&
                            SUCCEEDED(pNetworkConnectionCost->GetCost(&dwCost)) &&
                            dwCost == NLM_CONNECTION_COST_UNRESTRICTED &&
                            SUCCEEDED(pNetworkConnection->GetAdapterId(pInterfaceGuid)))
                        {
                            fFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else hr = E_NOINTERFACE;
            }

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && !fFound)
                hr = E_NOINTERFACE;
        }
    }
    if (fCoInitialized) CoUninitialize();
    return hr;
}
```

Once you have the interface GUID and [IP Helper APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the interface type. Here is some code I had that looks for non-cellular networks. You can take it and modify it to do what you need:

```
BOOL GetAdapterAddresses(
    _Out_ PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES * ppIAA
    )
{
    *ppIAA = NULL;

    DWORD len = 0;
    DWORD flags = GAA_FLAG_SKIP_ANYCAST|GAA_FLAG_SKIP_MULTICAST|GAA_FLAG_SKIP_DNS_SERVER;
    if (GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_UNSPEC, flags, NULL, NULL, &len) != ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
        return FALSE;

    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pIAA = (PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES)LocalAlloc(LPTR, len);
    if (pIAA) {
        GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_UNSPEC, flags, NULL, pIAA, &len);
        *ppIAA = pIAA;
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

bool IsNonCellularIfType(
    _In_ IFTYPE IfType
    )
{
    return // Ignore Loopback and WWAN
        IfType != IF_TYPE_SOFTWARE_LOOPBACK &&
        IfType != IF_TYPE_WWANPP &&
        IfType != IF_TYPE_WWANPP2;
}

DWORD GetNonCellularIfIndex(
    )
{
    DWORD IfIndex = (DWORD)(-1);
    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pIAA;
    if (GetAdapterAddresses(&pIAA)) {
        PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pIAAList = pIAA;
        while (pIAA) {
            // Look for Non-Cellular interface
            if (pIAA->OperStatus == IfOperStatusUp &&
                IsNonCellularIfType(pIAA->IfType)) {
                PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS_LH pUnicastAddr = pIAA->FirstUnicastAddress;
                // Look through all unicast addresses for valid IPv4 or IPv6 addresses
                while (pUnicastAddr) {
                    LPSOCKADDR pAddr = pUnicastAddr->Address.lpSockaddr;
                    if (pAddr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
                        if (!IN4_IS_ADDR_LINKLOCAL(&((SOCKADDR_IN *)pAddr)->sin_addr)) {
                            IfIndex = pIAA->IfIndex;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (pAddr->sa_family == AF_INET6) {
                        if (!IN6_IS_ADDR_LINKLOCAL(&((SOCKADDR_IN6 *)pAddr)->sin6_addr)) {
                            IfIndex = pIAA->IfIndex;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    pUnicastAddr = pUnicastAddr->Next;
                }
                // No need to keep looking any more?
                if (IfIndex != (DWORD)(-1))
                    break; // while (pIAA)
            }
            pIAA = pIAA->Next;
        }

        LocalFree(pIAAList);
    }
    return IfIndex;
}
```